# Having trouble with phpmyadmin

Tags: phpmyadmin

[image]

Whenever I want to go on phpmyadmin by the URL: locahost/phpmy/admin, it shows the error message "Fatal error: Class 'gettext_reader' not found in C:\xampp\phpMyAdmin\libraries\php-gettext\gettext.inc on line 140". Seeking for the solution..:)

Comment: Which phpMyAdmin version are you using? Are you using XAMPP?

Comment: Yahhh.... Latest one...

Answer (score 0):

ok, maybe i dont solve your problem, but i checked in my phpmyadmin 3.5.1 installed using wamp, i took a look into your error and found this:

gettext.inc (error file) has this line of code: `require('gettext.php');` in line 42, and this gettext.php file defines your `gettext_reader` class.

If both files are right (gettext.inc and gettext.php), is imposible you get that error.

I think, the only way you could get that error you are mentioning is gettext.php is modified/corrupted. Or line 42 `require('gettext.php');` is missing/commented

Compare your gettext.php with this: [gettext.php](http://piwigo.org/dev/browser/trunk/include/php-gettext/gettext.php?rev=5021)